# Generalizing norms: leaving out absolute homogeneity

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Given a function $\rho:X\to\mathbb{R}$ on a vector space $X$ which satisfies the following properties:

- $\rho(x)=0$ if and only if $x=0$
- $\rho(x+y)\leq\rho(x)+\rho(y)$
- $\rho(-x)=\rho(x)$

for any $x,y\in X$. Is the space belonging to the metric induced by $\rho$, i.e. $d_\rho(x,y)=\rho(x-y)$, normable?

**Background:** [This proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Metric_Induced_by_Norm_is_Metric) shows that the metric induced by a norm is in fact a metric, using only the special case $\rho(-x)=\rho(x)$ of the *absolute homogeneity* requirement of a norm. So I was wondering what happens if we leave it out.

**Own attempt:** Since *a topological vector space is normable if and only if it is Hausdorff and has a convex bounded neighborhood of $0$*, and since all metric spaces are Haussdorf, it suffices to show that it has a convex bounded neighborhood of $0$.

Could somebody help me prove or disprove the latter?
If $\rho(\alpha x)\leq|\alpha|\rho(x)$, for all $x\in X$ and all $0\leq\alpha\leq 1$, the unit ball is convex by the triangle inequality, but what about the general case above?

Answer (score 1):

The topology induced by the metric $d_\rho$ may be not even a topology of a [topological vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space). For instance, let $X=\mathbb R^2$, $\rho(x_1,x_2)=1$ if $x_2\ne 0$, and $\min\{1,|x_1|\} $ otherwise.  Then the scalar multiplication $\Bbb R\times X\to X$ is not continuous at the point $(0, (0,1))$.